# Combinatorial explosion of implicit objects

Tags: scala, typeclass

I have a case class, like this:

```
case class Container[T, M](value: T, modifier: M)
```

I want to make it possible to have an `Ordering` on `Container` for those `T` that have an `Ordering` too. I don't want to make `T <: Ordered[T]`, because `Container` should be able to contain non-orderable values as well.

My first try was to implement `Ordered`, like this:

```
case class Container[T, M](value: T, modifier: M) extends Ordered[Container[T, M]] {
  override def compare(that: Container[T, M])(implicit ev: Ordering[T]): Int = ev.compare(value, that.value)
}
```

But that obviously doesn't work: because of the `implicit` parameter, `compare` no longer implements the trait.

So then I decided to try a type class approach:

```
class ContainerOrdering[T, M](implicit ev: Ordering[T]) extends Ordering[Container[T, M]] {
  override def compare(x: Container[T, M], y: Container[T, M]): Int = ev.compare(x.value, y.value)
}
implicit object ContainerOrderingInt extends ContainerOrdering[Int, Int]
```

This works (if I also `import Ordering.Implicits._`), but now I have a new problem: for every type `M`, I need a separate implicit object. Now there aren't too many types that I want to use in the `M` position (in fact, they all derive from a sealed trait that I define elsewhere), but still it means a combinatorial explosion of implicit objects that I need to define. I'm OK with having a separate implicit object for each `T`, but `M` really should be orthogonal to this.

There must be a better way to do this. Maybe I can leverage the fact that `M` extends a sealed trait. However, I haven't been able to do so. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `Ordering` into a companion object!

```
object Container {
    implicit def ordering[T: Ordering, M] = new Ordering[Container[T, M]] {
        override def compare(x: Container[T, M], y: Container[T, M]): Int =
            implicitly[Ordering[T]].compare(x.value, y.value)
    }
}
```

Now you can use the ordering by using `import Container._` where needed.

(PS: The real trick was of course to make the ordering implicit to free you from defining every single ordering for each possible type.)

Comment: For some reason I hadn't thought of putting it in an implicit def, instead of an implicit object. That does the trick, indeed. Thanks!